# Multiprocessing, shared object which contains events

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to share a flag object which will contain multiple multiprocessing.event objects to communicate with multiple python processes created by Multiprocessing.

Will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following. Class `Foo` internally creates a list of `multiprocessing.Event` objects (in this case only 1 object for demo purposes) and an instance of `Foo` is passed to two processes:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Event
import time


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = []
        self.lst.append(Event())

def worker1(foo):
    event = foo.lst[0]
    t = time.time_ns()
    print('Waiting for event to be set...')
    event.wait()
    print('Wait satisfied, elapsed time =', (time.time_ns() - t) / 1_000_000_000.0)

def worker2(foo):
    event = foo.lst[0]
    time.sleep(2)
    event.set()

def main():
    foo = Foo()
    p1 = Process(target=worker1, args=(foo,))
    p2 = Process(target=worker2, args=(foo,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
Waiting for event to be set...
Wait satisfied, elapsed time = 2.0112978
```